# How to update Native Air Appilication?

Tags: actionscript, adobe, air, native

I created native air 2.0 app. (exe file) how to implement auto update for it?

Answer (score 0):

you're suppose to use a native updater because of security issues, but it's pretty easy to force your native installer into using the AIR update framework, as [demonstrated by Piotr Walczyszyn](http://www.riaspace.com/2010/08/nativeapplicationupdater-updater-for-air-apps-packaged-with-native-installers/).